# list containing generator expression invalid

Tags: cmake

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

project(hello)

set(SRCS    main.c  hello.c )
    
set(HEADERS hello.h )

add_executable(hello ${SRCS} ${HEADERS})

target_include_directories(hello PRIVATE 
    "inc1"
    "inc2"
)

target_include_directories(hello PRIVATE "headers")

set(var3)
list(APPEND var3 "inc3")
list(APPEND var3 "inc4")
list(APPEND var3 "$<TARGET_PROPERTY:hello,INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>")
message(STATUS "var3:${var3}")

list(LENGTH var3 list_len1)
message(STATUS "list_len1 :${list_len1}")
#file(GENERATE OUTPUT f.txt CONTENT ${list_len1})
file(GENERATE OUTPUT f.txt CONTENT ${var3})
```

it displays:

```
-- var3:inc3;inc4;$<TARGET_PROPERTY:hello,INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>
-- list_len1 :3
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:29 (file):
  file Unknown argument to GENERATE subcommand.
```

the line : file(GENERATE OUTPUT f.txt CONTENT ${var3})
generates the error. why?
we normally have a list of 3 elements, inc3, inc4 concatenated with the generator expression, which is when expanded :
/Users/windev/works/proj/inc1;/Users/windev/works/proj/inc2;/Users/windev/works/proj/headers

so why don't we have inc3,inc4,/Users/windev/works/proj/inc1;/Users/windev/works/proj/inc2;/Users/windev/works/proj/headers

printed in my f.txt

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Specification of [file(GENERATE)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.19/command/file.html#generate) command

```
file(GENERATE OUTPUT output-file
     <INPUT input-file|CONTENT content>
     [CONDITION expression] [TARGET target])
```

implies, that `content` is **exactly** a **single** argument.

Because your variable `var3` contains more than one value, then `${var3}` is expanded to more than one value. This is what the error message about.

Proper call to `file(GENERATE)` would be

```
file(GENERATE OUTPUT f.txt CONTENT "${var3}")
```

With that call list elements in the generated file will be separated by a semicolon(`;`).

If you want space separator between the elements, then you need to join the list elements before generating a file:

```
string(JOIN " " var3_string ${var3})
file(GENERATE OUTPUT f.txt CONTENT "${var3_string}")
```

or use `$<JOIN>` generator expression:

```
file(GENERATE OUTPUT f.txt CONTENT "$<JOIN:${var3}, >")
```

The advantage of the latter variant is that it joins **content** of the generator expression too. (The `string` command treats the whole generator expression as a single value).

Comment: thanks. if I just do set(var3) then list(APPEND var3 "$<TARGET_PROPERTY:hello,INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>")
list(LENGTH var3 list_len1)
file(GENERATE OUTPUT f.txt CONTENT ${list_len1})
why does the list if only of size one? If I dump var3 to f.txt I have : /Users/windev/works/proj/inc1;/Users/windev/works/proj/inc2;/Users/windev/works/proj/headers
which is a list and not a string

Comment: I have updated my answer with `$<JOIN>` variant. Probably, it is what you are looking for.

Comment: what I am currently trying to do is to iterate through $<TARGET_PROPERTY:hello,INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES> and print all elements in the list with a foreach kinda loop. I managed to do it with get_target_property(includes hello INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES) but I wanted to understand if it can be done with the genex. I am printing the result of the genex to the file because it's the only way to see its content (message operates at config phase)

Comment: `foreach` operates at the configuration stage too, so it cannot see the **expanded content** of the generator expression. Only `file(GENERATE)` can.

Comment: where can we find in the documentation the list of commands that execute at config time, and the one at generation time please? KR

Comment: and to conclude with this thread, my end goal is to use an existing cmakelist.txt and want to get the list of all include_directories. foreach item I want to append /*.h and call target_sources() with this list of items. At the end I just want to see the .h in the IDE. Is it possible to this with genex?

Comment: In the description of every command which works with generator expressions that ability is noted **explicitly**. E.g. documentation for [target_sources](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_sources.html) contains: ``Arguments to `target_sources` may use "generator expressions"``. Using [syntax of generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) you could add `/*.h` to every element in the existed expression, but you cannot perform **globbing**. So it seems that your intention is impossible.

Comment: Note, that it is not required to add headers into the `add_executable` call: compiling of the executable will succeed even without this addition. If you want to list header files for they being shown by IDE, then iterating over INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES is a wrong way.

Comment: "Arguments to `target_sources` may use "generator expressions". Does this mean : target_sources command is executed during the generation phase if it contains a generator expression, and during the configuration phase if not? Bests

Comment: Yes, accepting generator expressions means that the command interprets them when they are expanded. Because the expansion occurs at the end of configuration phace, their interpretation will be either at the end of configuration stage or at the build stage. In case of `target_sources` it is the former case.

Comment: when we use the GUI cmake tool it has "configure" and "generate" button. we see "end of configuration" in the log console after we click on configure. so does target_sources 
 does its job after this log or immediately after we click in "generate", or at the end of the "generate process" just before it really generate makefile, xcode project, ...